# Where does the energy go when a falling book hits the ground?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, collision

Where does the energy go when a falling book hits the ground?

Answer (score 1):

The energy of the falling book is dissipated as light, heat, sound, etc.

Comment: How do you get "light" from a falling book?

Comment: Interesting question. The book could fall at an angle and the frictional forces could generate some light. A falling metal would generate light for the same reason. I believe the author was concerned with the loss of energy after an object collides with the floor.  The central concept here was that the kinetic energy of the falling body gets converted to many other kinds of energy. I can list even more forms of energy. Potential energy of the ground? Potential energy of the book?

Comment: Thank you, and I was concerned with loss of energy and researching I couldn't understand the "light" being generated. You offered an explanation and I appreciate it!